# xlabel for first subplot pop up as a list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a beginner in `matplotlib` and I am trying to plot two bar diagrams. For the second plot the xlabels are fine, but for the first plot I got xlabels as a list, which also have unicode string format. Here is my code:

```
def get_val_from_dict(objects, n):
    x = []
    y = []

    for k,v in objects.items():
        probalities = float(v)/n
        cat = k 
        x.append(cat)
        y.append(probalities)

    return x,y
```

my `x`, `y` lists have following format for two datafiles:

```
[u'fast_food', u'school', u'bar', u'beauty', u'hairdresser', u'park', u'hotel', u'kiosk', u'pub', u'nightclub', u'supermarket', u'restaurant', u'bakery', u'pharmacy', u'doctors', u'fitness_centre', u'cafe', u'bank', u'clothes']
[0.08, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.05, 0.03, 0.19, 0.12, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.25, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.05, 0.01, 0.02]
[u'fast_food', u'school', u'bar', u'jewelry', u'beauty', u'hairdresser', u'shoes', u'park', u'museum', u'restaurant', u'kiosk', u'supermarket', u'pharmacy', u'bakery', u'greengrocer', u'cafe', u'bank', u'clothes']
[0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.15, 0.03, 0.09, 0.03, 0.21, 0.06, 0.03, 0.03, 0.06, 0.03, 0.06, 0.06, 0.03]




x_all = []
y_all = []
name_ = []

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
    fp = open(arg)
    contents = fp.read()
    name = arg

    n, data =  subsamples(contents)
    x, y = get_val_from_dict(data, n)

    x_all.append(x)
    y_all.append(y)
    name_.append(name)


count=0
for i in range(len(x_all)):
    count += 1

f, axarr = plt.subplots(count, sharex='col',   sharey='row')

for i in range(len(x_all)):
    axarr[i].set_title(label ="%s" %(name_[i]))

    axarr[i].bar(x_all[i], y_all[i])
    axarr[i].tick_params(axis='both', which='both')

    axarr[i].set_xlabel(x)
    axarr[i].set_xticklabels(x_all[i], rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

How can I plot the first subplot as the one below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, because you use `sharex`, you would not expect any labels below the first bar plot. So what you see there is the list set by `axarr[i].set_xlabel(x)`. Now `x` isn't really used at this place in the code; it is the list you get via `x, y = get_val_from_dict(data, n)`. I suppose you simply want to remove the line `axarr[i].set_xlabel(x)` from your code, or replace it with something more useful,

```
axarr[i].set_xlabel("My cool categories")
```

Note however that the number of categories is different for both plots and hence you have one unlabelled bar in the first plot. So I'd rather not share the axes here.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [u'fast_food', u'school', u'bar', u'beauty', u'hairdresser', u'park', u'hotel', u'kiosk', u'pub', u'nightclub', u'supermarket', u'restaurant', u'bakery', u'pharmacy', u'doctors', u'fitness_centre', u'cafe', u'bank', u'clothes']
y1 = [0.08, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.05, 0.03, 0.19, 0.12, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.25, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.05, 0.01, 0.02]
x2 = [u'fast_food', u'school', u'bar', u'jewelry', u'beauty', u'hairdresser', u'shoes', u'park', u'museum', u'restaurant', u'kiosk', u'supermarket', u'pharmacy', u'bakery', u'greengrocer', u'cafe', u'bank', u'clothes']
y2 = [0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.15, 0.03, 0.09, 0.03, 0.21, 0.06, 0.03, 0.03, 0.06, 0.03, 0.06, 0.06, 0.03]


x_all = [x1,x2]
y_all = [y1,y2]
name_ = ["A", "B"]

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(len(x_all), sharey='row')

for i in range(len(x_all)):
    axarr[i].set_title(label ="%s" %(name_[i]))

    axarr[i].bar(x_all[i], y_all[i])
    axarr[i].tick_params(axis='both', which='both')

    axarr[i].set_xlabel("My cool categories")
    axarr[i].set_xticklabels(x_all[i], rotation=90)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]